# Invalid Syntax at an equal sign

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

I keep getting this syntax error when it runs the line:

```
global merged_summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: You can only have one, a `global` statement or `assignment` statement not both. Split across 2 lines.

Comment: @EvandroPaula not sure this is a good dup, as this seems more about the use of `global` rather than the specific syntax error, which is because of mixing multiple statements in one line.

Comment: Thank you guys, I am gonna try splitting them now.

Comment: @AChampion I flag it as **possible** duplicate just because the root of question is how the global keyword works in Python.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to assign some value to a Variable name

variable naming will not support white spaces

```
 global merged_summary_op    
 merged_summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
```

You must need to follow some rules to do it

1. declare the variable as a global variable first
2. Then assign the value to it